# Tricky task about geometric progression

Tags: algorithm, math

Given two numbers l and r. Need to find length of the longest geometric progression which consists of some numbers between l and r — int-numbers in interval [l,r].
Note that the ratio of geometric progression can be non-integer.

For example, l = 11, r = 29. The longest sequence can be 12 18 27 with ratio 3/2

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: How does `12 18 27` include `11` and `29`? Maybe `l = 12` and `r = 27`?

Comment: If it doesn't have to start at the given `l` and end at the given `r`, then take the ratio to be `1.00001` and you'll obtain a much longer progression.

Comment: Do all the numbers in the geometric progression need to be integers? You never say that explicitly, but it seems to be implied. If you continue at this site, you need to learn to ask better questions and to show your work. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Indeed, without the restriction that all elements are integers, it looks like the length can be infinite.

Comment: Oh sorry for bad explanation .
All numbers between l and r are integers

Comment: IVlad, I meant that you can use l and r in your geometric progression

Answer (score 1):

We have `r = q**(n - 1) * l`, that is `r` equals the ratio to some power `n - 1` times `l`, where `n` is the number of terms in the series.

**Assuming the elements of the progression must be positive integers**

Assume we have a fixed `l`. In order to obtain integers, the ratio has to be a rational number `a / b` (with `gcd(a, b) == 1`) such that `b` is a factor of `l`.

If `b` appears in `l` to the power `k`, then the required progression can have at most `k` elements. The `k+1`th would not be an integer, since it will no longer have a factor of `b`.

Then we choose `a` to be minimal such that `a > b`. This is just `a = b+1`. So the ratio will always be `(b + 1) / b`.

This suggests the following algorithm for a given `l`:

1. Find the divisors of `l`.
2. For each one, `d`.
3. Find the number of terms possible with the ratio equal to `(d+1) / d`. Since geometric progressions grow fast, you can probably get away with a simple loop `while current <= r and term is integer`. Or you can find `n` like so:

   ```
   r = q**(n - 1) * l
   r / l = q**(n - 1)
   n - 1 = log base q of (r / l)
   n = int(log base q of (r / l)) + 1
   ```

But keep in mind that you must also account for how many integer terms this will generate. You can do that by keeping track of the power that each prime factor appears at in `d`.

4. Pick the one giving most terms.

For `12`, we have `12 = 2**2 * 3`.

For `2`, we have the ratio equal to `(2+1)/2 = 3/2`, and `3` terms.

For `3`, we have ratio equal to `4/3` and only two terms: `12, 16` (next one wouldn't be integer).

For `4`, we have the ratio equal to `5/4` and the terms `12, 15`.

For `6`, we have ratio equal to `7/6` and the terms `12, 14`.

Comment: Suppose `l = 36` and `r = 50`. Since `36 = 2² ⋅ 3²`, this algorithm will consider two ratios: `3/2` (the corresponding sequence is `(36)`) and `4/3` (the corresponding sequence is `(36, 48)`). But there is a better option: the ratio `7/6` with the sequence `(36, 42, 49)`.

Comment: That is true. I  suppose you can fix it by iterating the divisors instead of the prime factors. Will edit later today.

Comment: @user3290797 I updated the answer to consider all divisors. How does it look now?

Comment: I'd also add that since in the question the first term of the progression is not fixed, we need to apply this algorithm for every integer from `l` to `r-1`.

Comment: Yes, we do. I'm not sure if there's a better way - there might be a pattern involving divisors, but I'm not seeing it right away.